# Finding lasview tool from LAStools within QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, installation, lidar, lastools

I am trying to make a DEM from a .las file.

I have installed the LAStools directory and have the plugin:

[image: QGIS Processing toolbox]

I am wanting to use the `lasview` algorithm, but I can't see it in the standard toolbox I installed. Is there a way to add more algorithms?

Comment: There should be a blast2dem tool see https://rapidlasso.com/blast/blast2dem/ (did you set up lastools for qgis correctly? https://rapidlasso.com/2013/09/29/how-to-install-lastools-toolbox-in-qgis/)

Comment: Turns out I am an idiot!!!  :D  When I setup the LAS folder in QGIS I went 1 layer to deep.  IE I set the folder to the` \lastool\QGISToolbox  instead of \lastools`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked it out this morning - simple user error I had asked QGIS to look in the QGIS toolbox instead of lastools folder (Essentially I had gone layer to deep,  thinking that  I was wanting to look at the QGIS toolbox ,  however it looks at other files not just the QGIS toolbox)

[image: lastools folder]